# R: Reading tables from files and signing values from first row as names for each column for furhter inspection

Tags: r, dataframe, import, header

Let's assume we have the following data set in a `price.txt` file:

```
   date   price 1   price 2   price 3   price 4
      1      34.5      40.3       200      15.2
      2        32        51     187.8       0.1
      .         .         .         .         .
      .         .         .         .         .
```

Now I would like to handle this table in R with the following comand and just return it, to check that the data is correct and that following calucaltions make sense once I formulate them. So the code to initialize a dataframe from a textfile is:

```
data <- read.table("price.txt"), header = TRUE)
data
```

Now this would just return me:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : line 1 did not have 9 elements)
```

And assign the headers in a not desired way. So the issue seems to be with the spaces inside each header for each column. I was able to manually delete the spaces between, but that just seems to take time and be error prone if there are tens of headers. Table after manual correction would look like this:

```
   date    price1    price2    price3    price4
      1      34.5      40.3       200      15.2
      2        32        51     187.8       0.1
      .         .         .         .         .
      .         .         .         .         .
```

If I now run the `read.table` command as previously, everything would work nicely. I know how to "clean" the headers from extra spaces with C or Python, but is there any quick fix for the described problem in R or in the read.table's syntax. Tried to look for one, but wasn't able to get any working since the data has also spaces between the column headers, not just inside them. Thank's for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `read_file` and regex replacements:

```r
library(tidyverse)

read_file("data.txt") %>%
  str_remove_all("(?<=[:alnum:]) (?=[:alnum:])") %>%
  read.table(text = ., header = TRUE)

#   date price1 price2 price3 price4
# 1    1   34.5   40.3    200   15.2
# 2    2     32     51  187.8    0.1
# 3    .      .      .      .      .
# 4    .      .      .      .      .
```

Or in one line without pipe:

```r
read.table(text = str_remove_all(read_file("/Users/davidcsuka/Desktop/data.txt"), "(?<=[:alnum:]) (?=[:alnum:])"), header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do it without tidyverse-package other than a loop or somthing like that as I am not really familiar with the pipe-operator you used?

Comment: I redid it in one line without the pipe.